# python __delete__ not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying this simple python code:

```
class A:
  def __init__( self ):
    self.a = { 'k' : 'kk' }
  def __delete__( self, key ):
    del self.a[key]
```

This simple class doesn't work.

```
>>> a = A()
>>> del a['k']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'A' object does not support item deletion
```

So how should I proper implement item deletion in python ?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: `del( self, key ):` what is this supposed to be? Please post functioning code before asking a question.

Comment: If you want to implement the `__delete__` function (which is a magic method which is called when you "type" `del a[x]`) then you should implement the `__delete__` function i.e. rename `del` to `__delete__` and put a `def` in front

Comment: @syntonym: there is no `__delete__` hook method in Python, at least not outside of [*descriptors*](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html). There is a [`__del__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__), but that is only called when the object itself is deleted from memory. Given the *implementation* of the 'method' in the post, I suspect they were looking for [`object.__delitem__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delitem__).

Comment: I typed the code in a python3 shell and retyped it here.  I'm sorry for that `del(self,key)`, which obviously was not what I typed in the shell.

Comment: @MartijnPieters There is this one which I wrongly used : https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__del__#object.__delete__

Comment: @Lærne: right, that's on *descriptors*, which are objects you can add to a class and they'll have methods called on them when you interact with them via an instance of the class. That's how methods are bound and `property` objects do their work. And oops, I forgot about `__delete__` even existing (I simply forgot the name of that hook, I don't often need to use it).

Comment: @MartijnPieters You are of course right, that happens when I don't check the the names of magic methods. Should I delete my comment when it contains wrong information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to achieve the behavior of `del a['k']` (i.e. deleting an item by index) you should implement the [`__delitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delitem__) magic method:

```
In [1]: class A:
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         self.a = {'k': 'kk' }
   ...:     def __delitem__(self, key):
   ...:         del self.a[key]
   ...:         

In [2]: a = A()

In [3]: a.a
Out[3]: {'k': 'kk'}

In [4]: del a['k']

In [5]: a.a
Out[5]: {}
```